# VBA - If cell blank, delete entire row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
shMassPrelim.Range("AG2:AG" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

The above code is what I'm using to look for blank cells in column AG. However, Column AG is based upon an If formula. Is this the reason why I'm getting back "No Cells Blank" error?

Comment: If they have formulas in, then they aren't blank!

Comment: I changed my code to where I pull the formula values and copy paste them as value into column AG. Now my code is `shMassPrelim.Column("AG").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete` and I'm still getting an error where no blank cells are found but there are blank cells.

Comment: `""` is still a value, and means the cell isn't blank. Either you need to post the rest of the code to see what's happening or you need to use the `Range.AutoFilter()` method.

Comment: Yup I just went with the autofilter method.

Comment: Good choice, more flexible than `SpecialCells()` and a hell of a lot faster than looping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
Sub misc()
Dim cell As Range
Dim EMPTY_CELL As String
    EMPTY_CELL = ""
    For Each cell In Selection
        If Trim(cell.Value) = EMPTY_CELL Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will filter and delete the blank rows

```
Sub DeleteStuff()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "AG"), Cells(Rws, "AG"))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    Range("AG:AG").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0

End Sub
```